# I want to store spinner value in String and display it on a Textview

Tags: android

my code is working and I am getting the value on textview but its not changing on first click, suppose my spinner pops up and I select other value than at the same time my textview value doesn't changes it changes on the next click.

```
package com.vedicrishiastro.kundli.Screens.Extras;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.vedicrishiastro.kundli.R;
import com.vedicrishiastro.kundli.Screens.AbstractActivity;

public class Settings extends AbstractActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private LinearLayout linearSelectLang,linearSetDefault,linearSelectPanch;
    private TextView txtSelectLang,txtSetDefault,txtSelectPanch;
    private Spinner spinner1,spinner2,spinner3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        linearSelectLang = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearSelectLang);
        linearSetDefault = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearSetDefault);
        linearSelectPanch = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearSelectPanch);

        spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.settingSpinner1);
        spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.settingSpinner2);
        spinner3 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.settingSpinner3);

        txtSelectLang = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.selectLangtext);
        txtSetDefault = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.setdefaulttext);
        txtSelectPanch = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.selectPanchtext);

        linearSelectLang.setOnClickListener(this);
        linearSetDefault.setOnClickListener(this);
        linearSelectPanch.setOnClickListener(this);
        spinner1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spinner2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spinner3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        int id = view.getId();
        switch (id){
            case R.id.LinearSelectLang:
            {
                spinner1.performClick();
                String text = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                txtSelectLang.setText(text);
                spinner1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            break;
            case R.id.LinearSetDefault:
            {
                spinner2.performClick();
                String text = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                txtSetDefault.setText(text);
                spinner2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            break;
            case R.id.LinearSelectPanch:
            {
                spinner3.performClick();
                String text = spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString();
                txtSelectPanch.setText(text);
                spinner3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

I tried this but it isn't working

```
 case R.id.LinearSelectLang:
            {
                spinner1.performClick();
                spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        if (position == 0)
                        {
                            txtSelectLang.setText("English");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            txtSelectLang.setText("हिंदी");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });

            }
            break;
```

Comment: show what you are passing in spinner adapter

Comment: tried setOnItemSelectedListener() for spinner?

Comment: @Vera ?? its not working

Comment: @Mohit ?? its not working

Answer (score 1):

Create an *onItemSelectListener* for your *Spinner* and change the text every time an item is selected.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
      // DO it here
   }

});
```

Comment: is it not possible with onClick ?

Answer (score 1):

How about you use the spinner's `OnItemSelected` event?

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // your code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
```

Thing is, if you call `performClick`, the spinner pops out, but this call is not blocking. So you need the `OnItemSelectedListener` to get an async response with the input made by the user.

Calling `getSelectedItem` right after `performClick` (which opens the spinner?) will return the previously set element - which is the error you are facing.

Comment: i edited my question have a look , i used OnItemSelectedListener  but now the text is not getting displayed

Comment: You don't need to set the listener everytime you want to receive the item. Set it once after `spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.settingSpinner1);`

Comment: you mean onclicklistener ?

Comment: No. Set the `OnItemSelectedListener` for the spinner once, after `(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.settingSpinner1)`. Not in `onClick`.